# WooCommerce My Account page not clickable

Tags: wordpress, navigation, woocommerce

I am facing an issue with my WooCommerce end-points – If I am correct!

I created “My Account” navigation menu and renamed it as “Login/Register”; it has two sub-items – Cart & Checkout. The sub-items are clickable while the Login/Register menu itself isn’t functioning as a clickable link. I read through several posts and tried fixing it by creating different menus, deleting cache (I do not have any cache plugin now), going back to storefront theme (when I changed from my current child theme to Storefront, “My account”menu was clickable) but after restoring to my active child theme this isn’t working.

Please help.

Comment: So you have a problem with your child theme. Presumably a CSS issue, but difficult to diagnose without a link or any further information. Please examine your site with Chrome or Firefox's developer tools.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking. If you could help me with a basic idea of the problem, it would mean a lot. My site is; http://www.littlebighappiness.in/. You can see the issue if you try and click on the "LOGIN/REGISTER" nav menu.

Comment: `<a title="Login/Register" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">Login/Register </a>` It doesn't have an HREF so it won't link to anywhere. Go back and try again to add the "my account" page to your nav menus.

Comment: Should I create new menu - "My Account" or should I rename the Login/Register menu? Is there a particular step that I must follow?

Comment: Either should work. Create a menu item to the My Account page. Or add a URL to the custom Login/Register menu item.

Comment: Thanks Kathy. "Or add a URL to the custom Login/Register menu item." Can you help me understand how to achieve this - where do I add the URL?

Comment: If you created a custom link in the first place then you just have to edit it and you'll see the URL field. See [screenshot](http://imageshack.com/i/poQsy4XEp).

Comment: I have been unable to fix it. I did what you suggested. Here's what I did: https://snag.gy/QNicoU.jpg and the Login/Register Menu isn't functioning as it should, here https://snag.gy/4tDaQu.jpg